# Custom field Select Box Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to have a custom field with select box option. For example, I choose on the left side "League" and on the right side I can select from Select Box some value. Is this possible to do? Do you have an example? I can't use plugins because I created custom menu in the WP admin panel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found great tutorial here, so if someone needs here it is:
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes/